# How far away must a woodstove be from walls?

Tags: fireplace

I'm thinking of installing a woodstove in my cabin. How far away must I install it from the walls (which are surfaced with wood planks)?  Should I cover the nearby walls with bricks? Is there any other surface which would be better (I have seen sheet metal used in some places)?

Answer (score 4):

In the US, there should be a 36" clearance between any point on the stove and any point on a combustible wall. Shielding should be mounted on non-combustible spacers which allow air circulation behind the shield. UL-listed stoves with attached heat shields may be installed with less clearance according to manufacturer's specifications (you should consult their documentation before purchase).

[Reference](http://nasdonline.org/document/1254/d001052/wood-stove-installation-and-operation.html)

Comment: Great resource!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting a piece of [fiber cement board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_cement_siding) and covering it in a heat resistant clay wall tile.  You can screw the fiber board to the wall prior to tiling so there are no obvious fixings.